# Grabbing current map extent when using State Plane coordinate system?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, extents, configurable-map-viewer

When using the Share widget in the Configurable Map Viewer (CMV), I'm unable to grab and dispaly the current map extent while using a custom basemap projected in the State Plane coordinate system. It's my understanding that map.geographicExtent only works for the Web Mercator projection - I'd rather not change everything to Web Mercator.

Does anyone know a work around?

```
    define([
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dijit/_WidgetBase',
'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
'gis/dijit/_FloatingWidgetMixin',

'dojo/_base/lang',
'dojo/on',
'dojo/dom-attr',
'dojo/dom-construct',
'dojo/number',
'dojo/_base/event',

'esri/request',
'esri/urlUtils',
'esri/geometry/Extent',

// template
'dojo/text!./Share/templates/Share.html',

//i18n
'dojo/i18n!./Share/nls/Share',

//template widgets
'dijit/form/CheckBox',

// css
'xstyle/css!./Share/css/Share.css'
], function (
declare,
_WidgetBase,
_TemplatedMixin,
_WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
_FloatingWidgetMixin,

lang,
on,
domAttr,
domConstruct,
number,
event,

esriRequest,
urlUtils,
Extent,

template,

i18n

) {
return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,                             _FloatingWidgetMixin], {  
    name: 'Share',
    baseClass: 'cmvShareWidget',
    widgetsInTemplate: true,
    templateString: template,
    mapClickMode: null,

    // i18n
    i18n: i18n,

    //html: '<a href="#">Share</a>',
    html: '<a href="#"><img src="images/Share.png" title="Share"   onmouseover=this.src="images/ShareMO.png" onmouseout=this.src="images/Share.png"></a>',
    domTarget: 'shareDijit', //'helpDijit'

    url: window.location.href,
    mailURL: 'mailto:%20?subject={title}&body={summary}%20{url}',
    facebookURL: 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]={url}&p[images][0]={image}&p[title]={title}&p[summary]={summary}',
    twitterURL: 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={url}&text={title}&hashtags={hashtags}',
    googlePlusURL: 'https://plus.google.com/share?url={url}',

    bitlyAPI: location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten' : 'http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten',
    bitlyLogin: '',
    bitlyKey: '',

    title: '',
    image: '',
    summary: '',
    hashtags: '',

    windowSpecs: 'height=500, width=700, scrollbars=false',

    embedHeight: null,
    embedWidth: null,

    embedSizes: [
        {
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '640px'
        }, {
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '480px'
        }, {
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '320px'
        }, {
            'width': '800px',
            'height': '600px'
        }, {
            'width': '640px',
            'height': '480px'
        }, {
            'width': '480px',
            'height': '320px'
        }
    ],

    useExtent: false,
    extentEvt: null,

    draggable: true,

    postCreate: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        if (!this.parentWidget.toggleable) {
            this.parentWidget.draggable = this.draggable;
            var share = domConstruct.place(this.html, this.domTarget);
            on(share, 'click', lang.hitch(this.parentWidget, 'show'));
        }

        this.own(on(this.extentInput, 'click', lang.hitch(this, this.useExtentUpdate)));
        this.setExtentChecked();

        this.watch('url', this.updateUrl);
        this.watch('embedSizes', this.setSizeOptions);
        this.watch('embed', this.updateEmbed);
        this.watch('bitlyUrl', this.updateBitlyUrl);
        this.watch('useExtent', this.useExtentChanged);

        this.updateUrl();
        this.shareLink();
    },

    startup: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);

        // set sizes for select box
        this.setSizeOptions();

        // handle any query string parameters
        // like zoom to extent
        this.handeQueryParameters();

        // set embed url
        this.updateUrl();

        // update the widget user interface
        this.updateUI();
    },

    handeQueryParameters: function () {
        var urlObject = urlUtils.urlToObject(window.location.href);
        urlObject.query = urlObject.query || {};
        if (urlObject.query.extent) {
            var vals = urlObject.query.extent.split(',');
            if (vals.length === 4 && !isNaN(vals[0]) && !isNaN(vals[1]) && !isNaN(vals[2]) && !isNaN(vals[3])) {
                // assumes lat/lng
                var extent = new Extent({
                    xmin: number.parse(vals[0]),
                    ymin: number.parse(vals[1]),
                    xmax: number.parse(vals[2]),
                    ymax: number.parse(vals[3]),
                    spatialReference: {
                        wkid: 102696
                        //wkid: 102100
                    }
                });
                this.map.setExtent(extent);
            }
        }
    },

    updateUI: function () {

        // select menu change
        this.own(on(this.comboBoxNode, 'change', lang.hitch(this, function (evt) {
            this.set('embedWidth', this.get('embedSizes')[parseInt(evt.currentTarget.value, 10)].width);
            this.set('embedHeight', this.get('embedSizes')[parseInt(evt.currentTarget.value, 10)].height);
            this.setEmbedCode();
        })));

        // facebook click
        this.own(on(this.facebookButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('facebookURL'));
        })));

        // twitter click
        this.own(on(this.twitterButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('twitterURL'));
        })));

        // google plus click
        this.own(on(this.gplusButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('googlePlusURL'));
        })));

        // email click
        this.own(on(this.emailButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('mailURL'), true);
        })));

        // link click
        this.own(on(this.linkButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('url'), false, true);
        })));

        // link box click
        this.own(on(this.shareMapUrlText, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.shareMapUrlText.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
        })));

        // link box mouseup stop for touch devices
        this.own(on(this.shareMapUrlText, 'mouseup', function (evt) {
            event.stop(evt);
        }));

        // embed box click
        this.own(on(this.embedNode, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.embedNode.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
        })));

        // embed box mouseup stop for touch devices
        this.own(on(this.embedNode, 'mouseup', function (evt) {
            event.stop(evt);
        }));

    },

    *updateUrl: function () {
        // nothing currently shortened
        this.shortened = null;
        // no bitly shortened
        this.set('bitlyUrl', null);
        // vars
        var map = this.get('map'),
            url = this.get('url'),
            useSeparator;
        // get url params
        var urlObject = urlUtils.urlToObject(window.location.href);
        urlObject.query = urlObject.query || {};
        // include extent in url
        if (this.get('useExtent') && map) {
            // get map extent in geographic
            var gExtent = map.geographicExtent;
            // set extent string
            urlObject.query.extent = gExtent.xmin.toFixed(10) + ',' + gExtent.ymin.toFixed(10) + ',' + gExtent.xmax.toFixed(10) + ',' + gExtent.ymax.toFixed(10);
        } else {
            urlObject.query.extent = null;
        }*

        // create base url
        url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
        // each param
        for (var i in urlObject.query) {
            if (urlObject.query[i] && urlObject.query[i] !== 'config') {
                // use separator
                if (useSeparator) {
                    url += '&';
                } else {
                    url += '?';
                    useSeparator = true;
                }
                url += i + '=' + urlObject.query[i];
            }
        }
        // update url
        this.set('url', url);
        // reset embed code
        this.setEmbedCode();
        // set url value
        domAttr.set(this.shareMapUrlText, 'value', url);

    },

    updateEmbed: function () {
        domAttr.set(this.embedNode, 'value', this.get('embed'));
    },

    setEmbedCode: function () {
        var es = '<iframe width=\'' + this.get('embedWidth') + '\' height=\'' + this.get('embedHeight') + '\' src=\'' + this.get('url') + '\' frameborder=\'0\' scrolling=\'no\'></iframe>';
        this.set('embed', es);
    },

    setExtentChecked: function () {
        this.extentInput.setValue(this.useExtent);
        if (this.useExtent) {
            this.extentEvt = this.own(this.map.on('extent-change', lang.hitch(this, function () {
                this.updateUrl();
            })));
        } else if (this.extentEvt && this.extentEvt.remove) {
            this.extentEvt.remove();
        }
    },

    useExtentUpdate: function () {
        this.set('useExtent', this.extentInput.getValue());
    },

    useExtentChanged: function () {
        this.updateUrl();
        this.shareLink();
        this.setExtentChecked();
    },

    setSizeOptions: function () {
        // clear select menu
        this.comboBoxNode.innerHTML = '';
        // if embed sizes exist
        if (this.get('embedSizes') && this.get('embedSizes').length) {
            // map sizes
            for (var i = 0; i < this.get('embedSizes').length; i++) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    this.set('embedWidth', this.get('embedSizes')[i].width);
                    this.set('embedHeight', this.get('embedSizes')[i].height);
                }
                var option = domConstruct.create('option', {
                    value: i,
                    innerHTML: this.get('embedSizes')[i].width + ' x ' + this.get('embedSizes')[i].height
                });
                domConstruct.place(option, this.comboBoxNode, 'last');
            }
        }
    },

    updateBitlyUrl: function () {
        var bitly = this.get('bitlyUrl');
        if (bitly) {
            domAttr.set(this.shareMapUrlText, 'value', bitly);
            domAttr.set(this.linkButton, 'href', bitly);
        }
    },

    shareLink: function () {
        if (this.get('bitlyAPI') && this.get('bitlyLogin') && this.get('bitlyKey')) {
            var currentUrl = this.get('url');
            // not already shortened
            if (currentUrl !== this.shortened) {
                // set shortened
                this.shortened = currentUrl;
                // make request
                esriRequest({
                    url: this.get('bitlyAPI'),
                    callbackParamName: 'callback',
                    content: {
                        uri: currentUrl,
                        login: this.get('bitlyLogin'),
                        apiKey: this.get('bitlyKey'),
                        f: 'json'
                    },
                    load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
                        if (response && response.data && response.data.url) {
                            this.set('bitlyUrl', response.data.url);
                        }
                    }),
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },

    configureShareLink: function (Link, isMail, isLink) {
        // replace strings
        var fullLink = lang.replace(Link, {
            url: encodeURIComponent(this.get('bitlyUrl') ? this.get('bitlyUrl') : this.get('url')),
            image: encodeURIComponent(this.get('image')),
            title: encodeURIComponent(this.get('title')),
            summary: encodeURIComponent(this.get('summary')),
            hashtags: encodeURIComponent(this.get('hashtags'))
        });
        // email link
        if (isMail) {
            window.location.href = fullLink;
        // just a normal link
        } else if (isLink) {
            window.open(fullLink);
        } else {
            console.log(this.get('windowSpecs'));
            window.open(fullLink, 'cmvShare', this.get('windowSpecs'));
        }
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to piece together some code that essentially just re-projects the coords via a geometry service. I'm assuming that this is somewhat a 'duh' answer to most, but just throwing it out there.  That being said, I can get an extent but it doesn't seem to zoom in to the correct location.  I'll create a separate post for this issue if I can't figure it out.  Code posted below:

```
/*eslint strict: 0, no-console: 0 */
define([
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dojo/Deferred',
'dijit/_WidgetBase',
'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
'gis/dijit/_FloatingWidgetMixin',

'dojo/_base/lang',
'esri/config',
'esri/SpatialReference',
'dojo/on',
'dojo/dom-attr',
'dojo/dom-construct',
'dojo/number',
'dojo/_base/event',

'esri/request',
'esri/urlUtils',
'esri/geometry/Extent',

// template
'dojo/text!./Share/templates/Share.html',

//i18n
'dojo/i18n!./Share/nls/Share',

//template widgets
'dijit/form/CheckBox',

// css
'xstyle/css!./Share/css/Share.css'
], function (
declare,
Deferred,
_WidgetBase,
_TemplatedMixin,
_WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
_FloatingWidgetMixin,

lang,
esriConfig,
SpatialReference,
on,
domAttr,
domConstruct,
number,
event,

esriRequest,
urlUtils,
Extent,

template,

i18n

) {
return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,    _FloatingWidgetMixin], {
    name: 'Share',
    baseClass: 'cmvShareWidget',
    widgetsInTemplate: true,
    templateString: template,
    mapClickMode: null,

    // i18n
    i18n: i18n,

    //html: '<a href="#">Share</a>',
    html: '<a href="#"><img src="images/Share.png" title="Share" onmouseover=this.src="images/ShareMO.png" onmouseout=this.src="images/Share.png"></a>',
    domTarget: 'shareDijit', //'helpDijit'

    url: window.location.href,
    mailURL: 'mailto:%20?subject={title}&body={summary}%20{url}',
    facebookURL: 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]={url}&p[images][0]={image}&p[title]={title}&p[summary]={summary}',
    twitterURL: 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={url}&text={title}&hashtags={hashtags}',
    googlePlusURL: 'https://plus.google.com/share?url={url}',

    bitlyAPI: location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten' : 'http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten',
    bitlyLogin: '',
    bitlyKey: '',

    title: '',
    image: '',
    summary: '',
    hashtags: '',

    windowSpecs: 'height=500, width=700, scrollbars=false',

    embedHeight: null,
    embedWidth: null,

    embedSizes: [
        {
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '640px'
        }, {
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '480px'
        }, {
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '320px'
        }, {
            'width': '800px',
            'height': '600px'
        }, {
            'width': '640px',
            'height': '480px'
        }, {
            'width': '480px',
            'height': '320px'
        }
    ],

    useExtent: false,
    extentEvt: null,

    draggable: true,

    postCreate: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);
        if (!this.parentWidget.toggleable) {
            this.parentWidget.draggable = this.draggable;
            var share = domConstruct.place(this.html, this.domTarget);
            on(share, 'click', lang.hitch(this.parentWidget, 'show'));
        }

        this.own(on(this.extentInput, 'click', lang.hitch(this, this.useExtentUpdate)));
        this.setExtentChecked();

        this.watch('url', this.updateUrl);
        this.watch('embedSizes', this.setSizeOptions);
        this.watch('embed', this.updateEmbed);
        this.watch('bitlyUrl', this.updateBitlyUrl);
        this.watch('useExtent', this.useExtentChanged);

        this.updateUrl();
        this.shareLink();
    },

    startup: function () {
        this.inherited(arguments);

        // set sizes for select box
        this.setSizeOptions();

        // set embed url
        this.updateUrl();

        // update the widget user interface
        this.updateUI();
    },

    /* handeQueryParameters: function () {
        var urlObject = urlUtils.urlToObject(window.location.href);
        urlObject.query = urlObject.query || {};
        if (urlObject.query.extent) {
            var vals = urlObject.query.extent.split(',');
            if (vals.length === 4 && !isNaN(vals[0]) && !isNaN(vals[1]) && !isNaN(vals[2]) && !isNaN(vals[3])) {
                // assumes lat/lng
                var extent = new Extent({
                    xmin: number.parse(vals[0]),
                    ymin: number.parse(vals[1]),
                    xmax: number.parse(vals[2]),
                    ymax: number.parse(vals[3]),
                    spatialReference: {
                        wkid: 102696
                        //wkid: 102100
                    }
                });
                this.map.setExtent(extent);
            }
        }
    }, */

    updateUI: function () {

        // select menu change
        this.own(on(this.comboBoxNode, 'change', lang.hitch(this, function (evt) {
            this.set('embedWidth', this.get('embedSizes')[parseInt(evt.currentTarget.value, 10)].width);
            this.set('embedHeight', this.get('embedSizes')[parseInt(evt.currentTarget.value, 10)].height);
            this.setEmbedCode();
        })));

        // facebook click
        this.own(on(this.facebookButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('facebookURL'));
        })));

        // twitter click
        this.own(on(this.twitterButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('twitterURL'));
        })));

        // google plus click
        this.own(on(this.gplusButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('googlePlusURL'));
        })));

        // email click
        this.own(on(this.emailButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('mailURL'), true);
        })));

        // link click
        this.own(on(this.linkButton, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.configureShareLink(this.get('url'), false, true);
        })));

        // link box click
        this.own(on(this.shareMapUrlText, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.shareMapUrlText.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
        })));

        // link box mouseup stop for touch devices
        this.own(on(this.shareMapUrlText, 'mouseup', function (evt) {
            event.stop(evt);
        }));

        // embed box click
        this.own(on(this.embedNode, 'click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
            this.embedNode.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
        })));

        // embed box mouseup stop for touch devices
        this.own(on(this.embedNode, 'mouseup', function (evt) {
            event.stop(evt);
        }));

    },

    updateUrl: function () {
        // nothing currently shortened
        this.shortened = null;
        // no bitly shortened
        this.set('bitlyUrl', null);
        // vars
        var map = this.get('map'),
            url = this.get('url'),
            useSeparator;
        // get url params
        var urlObject = urlUtils.urlToObject(window.location.href);
        urlObject.query = urlObject.query || {};
        urlObject.query.extent = null;
        // include extent in url
        /*if (this.get('useExtent') && map) {
            // get map extent in geographic
           /var gExtent = map.geographicExtent;
            // set extent string
            urlObject.query.extent = gExtent.xmin.toFixed(10) + ',' + gExtent.ymin.toFixed(10) + ',' + gExtent.xmax.toFixed(10) + ',' + gExtent.ymax.toFixed(10);
        } else {
            urlObject.query.extent = null;
        }*/
        this._projectGeometry().then(lang.hitch(this, function (result) {
            if (result) {
                var gExtent = result;
                  //urlObject.query.extent = gExtent.xmin + ',' + gExtent.ymin + ',' + gExtent.xmax + ',' + gExtent.ymax;
                urlObject.query.extent = gExtent.xmin.toFixed(0) + ',' + gExtent.ymin.toFixed(0) + ',' + gExtent.xmax.toFixed(0) + ',' + gExtent.ymax.toFixed(0);
        }
        // create base url
        url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
        // each param
        for (var i in urlObject.query) {
            if (urlObject.query[i] && urlObject.query[i] !== 'config') {
                // use separator
                if (useSeparator) {
                    url += '&';
                } else {
                    url += '?';
                    useSeparator = true;
                }
                url += i + '=' + urlObject.query[i];
            }
        }
        // update url
        this.set('url', url);
        // reset embed code
        this.setEmbedCode();
        // set url value
        domAttr.set(this.shareMapUrlText, 'value', url);
        }));
    },

    _projectGeometry: function () {
        var deferred = new Deferred();
         var map = this.get("map");
        if (this.get("useExtent") && map) {
            // get map extent in geographic
            if (map.geographicExtent) {
                deferred.resolve(map.geographicExtent);
                // var gExtent = map.geographicExtent;
                // set extent string
            } else {
                //project the extent to geographic
                var outSR = new SpatialReference({
                    "wkid": 102696
                });
                esriConfig.defaults.geometryService.project([map.extent], outSR).then(lang.hitch(this, function (result) {
                    if (result.length) {
                        var projectedExtent = result[0];
                        deferred.resolve(projectedExtent);

                }}));

            }

        } else {
            deferred.resolve(null);
        }

        return deferred.promise; 

    }, 

    updateEmbed: function () {
        domAttr.set(this.embedNode, 'value', this.get('embed'));
    },

    setEmbedCode: function () {
        var es = '<iframe width=\'' + this.get('embedWidth') + '\' height=\'' + this.get('embedHeight') + '\' src=\'' + this.get('url') + '\' frameborder=\'0\' scrolling=\'no\'></iframe>';
        this.set('embed', es);
    },

    setExtentChecked: function () {
        this.extentInput.setValue(this.useExtent);
        if (this.useExtent) {
            this.extentEvt = this.own(this.map.on('extent-change', lang.hitch(this, function () {
                this.updateUrl();
            })));
        } else if (this.extentEvt && this.extentEvt.remove) {
            this.extentEvt.remove();
        }
    },

    useExtentUpdate: function () {
        this.set('useExtent', this.extentInput.getValue());
    },

    useExtentChanged: function () {
        this.updateUrl();
        this.shareLink();
        this.setExtentChecked();
    },

    setSizeOptions: function () {
        // clear select menu
        this.comboBoxNode.innerHTML = '';
        // if embed sizes exist
        if (this.get('embedSizes') && this.get('embedSizes').length) {
            // map sizes
            for (var i = 0; i < this.get('embedSizes').length; i++) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    this.set('embedWidth', this.get('embedSizes')[i].width);
                    this.set('embedHeight', this.get('embedSizes')[i].height);
                }
                var option = domConstruct.create('option', {
                    value: i,
                    innerHTML: this.get('embedSizes')[i].width + ' x ' + this.get('embedSizes')[i].height
                });
                domConstruct.place(option, this.comboBoxNode, 'last');
            }
        }
    },

    updateBitlyUrl: function () {
        var bitly = this.get('bitlyUrl');
        if (bitly) {
            domAttr.set(this.shareMapUrlText, 'value', bitly);
            domAttr.set(this.linkButton, 'href', bitly);
        }
    },

    shareLink: function () {
        if (this.get('bitlyAPI') && this.get('bitlyLogin') && this.get('bitlyKey')) {
            var currentUrl = this.get('url');
            // not already shortened
            if (currentUrl !== this.shortened) {
                // set shortened
                this.shortened = currentUrl;
                // make request
                esriRequest({
                    url: this.get('bitlyAPI'),
                    callbackParamName: 'callback',
                    content: {
                        uri: currentUrl,
                        login: this.get('bitlyLogin'),
                        apiKey: this.get('bitlyKey'),
                        f: 'json'
                    },
                    load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
                        if (response && response.data && response.data.url) {
                            this.set('bitlyUrl', response.data.url);
                        }
                    }),
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },

    configureShareLink: function (Link, isMail, isLink) {
        // replace strings
        var fullLink = lang.replace(Link, {
            url: encodeURIComponent(this.get('bitlyUrl') ? this.get('bitlyUrl') : this.get('url')),
            image: encodeURIComponent(this.get('image')),
            title: encodeURIComponent(this.get('title')),
            summary: encodeURIComponent(this.get('summary')),
            hashtags: encodeURIComponent(this.get('hashtags'))
        });
        // email link
        if (isMail) {
            window.location.href = fullLink;
        // just a normal link
        } else if (isLink) {
            window.open(fullLink);
        } else {
            console.log(this.get('windowSpecs'));
            window.open(fullLink, 'cmvShare', this.get('windowSpecs'));
        }
    }

});
```

});